# Tagging questions for Dojo version 1.7 and above (AMD)

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

I have some dilemma asking questions about [dojo](/questions/tagged/dojo). There was a significant technology shift in version 1.7 - changing `require` syntax (switching to AMD) and remodularization. The code from old version won't work in new version without rewrite.

Specifying dojo version in question text is a good practice, however I'd like to use this in tags. There's a tag [dojo-1.7](/questions/tagged/dojo-1.7), but I'm using the version 1.9. However, tagging it as [dojo-1.9](/questions/tagged/dojo-1.9) doesn't make sense, because I'm not using anything specific for version 1.9.

How should I tag questions about Dojo, to signal I'm using version >=1.7 (with AMD)? Using [dojo](/questions/tagged/dojo) with tag [amd](/questions/tagged/amd)? Maybe creating [dojo-amd](/questions/tagged/dojo-amd)? Creating new tag would make more sense, if accompanied with retagging of existing questions.

I just want the tags to be more 'speaking', such as in case of [jsf](/questions/tagged/jsf) and [jsf-2](/questions/tagged/jsf-2). Unfortunatelly, dojo hasn't change major version when doing major technological switch, making it harder to deal with tagging questions.